# exploit in my php script

Tags: php, exploit

i have a famous script installed on my server 
a programmer told me that i have a code inside one of the pages which can be used to execute any code or function  and grep all data of my box

the code is

```
function fileRequestHandler($handler, $module = false, $file = false){
global $test_conf;

switch ($handler) {
    case 'reload':
// AJAX handler for reload event
        $response = do_reload();
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;
    case 'file':
        /** Handler to pass-through file requests
         * Looks for "module" and "file" variables, strips .. and only allows normal filename characters.
         * Accepts only files of the type listed in $allowed_exts below, and sends the corresponding mime-type,
         * and always interprets files through the PHP interpreter. (Most of?) the environment is available,
         * including $db and $astman, and the user is authenticated.
         */
        if (!$module || !$file) {
            die_myscript("unknown");
        }
//TODO: this could probably be more efficient
        $module = str_replace('..', '.', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]/', '', $module));
        $file = str_replace('..', '.', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]/', '', $file));

        $allowed_exts = array(
            '.js' => 'text/javascript',
            '.js.php' => 'text/javascript',
            '.css' => 'text/css',
            '.css.php' => 'text/css',
            '.html.php' => 'text/html',
            '.php' => 'text/html',
            '.jpg.php' => 'image/jpeg',
            '.jpeg.php' => 'image/jpeg',
            '.png.php' => 'image/png',
            '.gif.php' => 'image/gif',
        );
```

what's the problem of the code here ?? , what type of action could be passed through that code ??

how could i close it
thanks

Comment: You don't close the `switch`

Comment: You have to explain the context this code is used in. Is this a handler for file upload? generally, security vulneribalities are triggered by user input. What variables in your code are given by the user? Be more specific

Comment: switch for sure closed , but i did not paste the full code

Comment: What is this famous script you speak of?

Comment: @deadlock , iam not sure i can understand you , iam not php fan , so i just post the code here :( from which the programmer told me

Comment: @M.Hossam The code you posted seems fine to me, but I can't see the sections that you did not post. Also the issues could be in other methods than the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=fileRequestHandler&oq=fileRequestHandler&aqs=chrome..69i57.627j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20function%20fileRequestHandler) learned me that you where looking for this code:

http://cxsecurity.com/issue/WLB-2014020088

```
function fileRequestHandler($handler, $module = false, $file = false)
{
    global $amp_conf;

    switch ($handler) {
        case 'reload':
// AJAX handler for reload event
            $response = do_reload();
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);
            break;
        case 'file':
            /** Handler to pass-through file requests
             * Looks for "module" and "file" variables, strips .. and only allows normal filename
             * characters.
             * Accepts only files of the type listed in $allowed_exts below, and sends the corresponding mime-type,
             * and always interprets files through the PHP interpreter. (Most of?) the freepbx environment is available,
             * including $db and $astman, and the user is authenticated.
             */
            if (!$module || !$file) {
                die_freepbx("unknown");
            }
//TODO: this could probably be more efficient
            $module = str_replace('..', '.', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]/', '', $module));
            $file = str_replace('..', '.', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\_\.]/', '', $file));

            $allowed_exts = array(
                '.js' => 'text/javascript',
                '.js.php' => 'text/javascript',
                '.css' => 'text/css',
                '.css.php' => 'text/css',
                '.html.php' => 'text/html',
                '.php' => 'text/html',
                '.jpg.php' => 'image/jpeg',
                '.jpeg.php' => 'image/jpeg',
                '.png.php' => 'image/png',
                '.gif.php' => 'image/gif',
            );
            foreach ($allowed_exts as $ext => $mimetype) {
                if (substr($file, -1 * strlen($ext)) == $ext) {
                    $fullpath = 'modules/' . $module . '/' . $file;
                    if (file_exists($fullpath)) {
// file exists, and is allowed extension

// image, css, js types - set Expires to 24hrs in advance so the client does
// not keep checking for them. Replace from header.php
                        if (!$amp_conf['DEVEL']) {
                            header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 86400) . ' GMT', true);
                            header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate', true);
                        }
                        header("Content-type: " . $mimetype);
                        ob_start();
                        include($fullpath);
                        ob_end_flush();
                        exit();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            die_freepbx("../view/not allowed");
            break;
        case 'api':
            if (isset($_REQUEST['function']) && function_exists($_REQUEST['function'])) {
                $function = $_REQUEST['function'];
                $args = isset($_REQUEST['args']) ? $_REQUEST['args'] : '';

//currently works for one arg functions, eventually need to clean this up to except more args
                $result = $function($args);
                $jr = json_encode($result);
            } else {
                $jr = json_encode(null);
            }
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo $jr;
            break;
    }
    exit();
}

//Function is called at admin / config . php at line 132

if (!in_array($display, array('noauth', 'badrefer'))
    && isset($_REQUEST['handler'])
) {
    $module = isset($_REQUEST['module']) ? $_REQUEST['module'] : '';
    $file = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ? $_REQUEST['file'] : '';
    fileRequestHandler($_REQUEST['handler'], $module, $file);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: yes that's correct , the exploit in my freepbx script
but i donot want to tell that , not to make it popular :( 
but seems that the exploit has been published

Comment: I can see that `$_REQUEST['function']` is executed without any sanitization. I think this is can lead to arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @M.Hossam Then I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @veelen , iam asking what the hacker can do with that exploit

Comment: @M.Hossam he can pass a function to be executed as a parameter. eg. `url?function=shell_exec("cat /etc/passwd")`

Comment: @deadlock
i tried that on my script . not working

Comment: @M.Hossam that was just an explanatory example. Of course your input has to be crafted to go along with the exploit. I am not sure if it's a good thing to do that here on SOF!! I recommend that you read the article as the vulnerability is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

All $_REQUEST are not sanitized. 
as others said, you must sanitize user inputs ($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST etc...)
if you can not deal with php I recommend you to hire a good php programmer to secure your application. Or better, do not use scripts which contains like these vulnerabilities.

and if these are not option for you, add this code to all your php files after `<?php` tag (or in to your config.php if it including  by all php files);

```
// sanitize $_GET variables
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);        

// sanitize $_POST variables
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);       

// sanitize $_REQUEST variables
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val){
$_REQUEST[$key] = @filter_var(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($val), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
```

Note that this code may breake some part of your application especially working with special chars...

Comment: This won’t help here. Read http://cxsecurity.com/issue/WLB-2014020088

Comment: @Gumbo, please read my answer again. Of course this will help to sanitize user data. But is this enough?, of course not, read what I wrote. Plus there is noting about this will not help here, in your link. They recommend a firewall and a paid product (which is not related the ops question) to cover this vulnerability. Op is asking about application security, not server security... we can not recommend firewall or server related paid solutions about covering application security. App security and server security are different things.

Comment: Sanitizing the input as you suggest won’t help as exploiting the mentioned vulnerability does not require any of the characters removed/encoded by FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING. The linked page mentions the example `config.php?handler=api&function=system&args=id`, which is results in `system('id')`.

Comment: @Gumbo, I am sorry. yes you are right... this script has vulnerabilities like hell. developer did not clean user data and additionally, he/she use bad coding practices... I did not check the code flow itself. so I am sorry... As I recommend in my answer, I will never use this kind of scripts...